# Where can I get wlWriterEditableSmartContent?

Tags: windows-live-writer

I've found a bunch of web sites that use wlWriterEditableSmartContent to show source code in a pretty-print sort of way.  Where can I get that class to use on my own web sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the correct answer to my question...

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/beautyOfCode